# How can I replace UINavigationController as left hand view in UISplitViewController in Interface Builder?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

My main view controller in my iPhone app is a UITabBarController. I want to use it as the left-hand view controller in a UISplitViewController, but Interface Builder doesn't want to play nice and let me do it. Is it possible to replace the left view controller in a UISplitViewController? If so, how do I do it?

I realize I can do this in code, but I'd prefer to do it in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't replace the UINavigationController with a stock UITabBarController because the UITabBarController only supports portrait by default. So I'd have to inherit from UITabBarController and override that method etc etc which I don't want to do.

After playing around with UISplitViewController, though, I find it to be mostly useless, so I've abandoned it as my root view controller.